# jQuery conditional statement between trim.().split() and 'exact match'

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that checks an input field and compares it to a list group. If the characters/words are found within a list item, it will only show thoses list items containing the exact match. I am using trim().split() to detect more that one word/ phrase.

Here my code:

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.filterlist>li').show();
  } else {
    var subValues = valThis.trim().split(', ');
    $('.filterlist>li').each(function () {
      var node = $(this);
      var text = node.text().toLowerCase();  
      if (subValues.some(function (word) {
        return text.indexOf(word) !== -1;
      })) {
        node.show();  
      }
      else {
        node.hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<ul class="filterlist" style="list-style:none;">
  <li>1. red</li>
  <li>2. blue</li>
  <li>3. red blue yellow</li>
  <li>4. blue red yellow</li>
  <li>5. red yellow</li>
  <li>6. red green</li>
</ul>
```

This works great, if you input 'red, yellow' all items containing either word shows only the list items that contain those words i.e all items will show except, for item '2' as it only has 'blue'.
On the other hand if you input 'red yellow', it would only return items '4' and '5', because of the exact match.

*However my question is*, is there a way to keep this function but add in a condition somehow that would allow a user to show the items containing only what is input, but does not have to be an exact match? i.e. input = 'red+yellow' > lists: '3', '4' and '5' or input = 'blue+green' > no lists are shown.

I have tried using the selectors ':contains()' and ':not(:contains())', but just can't get my head around it.

Any help would be massively appreciative.

**UPDATED:** 
Now adds in the input values as a class/s into the li tag.

```
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  /* remove split character */
  var valClass = valThis.replace(',','');

  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.filterlist>li').show();
  } else {
    var subValues = valThis.trim().split(', ');
    $('.filterlist>li').each(function () {
      var node = $(this);
      var text = node.text().toLowerCase();  
      if (subValues.some(function (word) {
        return text.indexOf(word) !== -1;
      })) {
        node.show();
        $(this).removeClass().addClass(valClass);  
      }
      else {
        node.hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that the words you're searching for can be placed on the `li` as classes? eg `<li class="red blue yellow">3. red blue yellow</li>`? If it is then it becomes much, much simpler to achieve what you need. Let me know if so, and I'll give you an example of how to structure the logic

Comment: let me have a quick play

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of the current scenario https://jsfiddle.net/5v1vx6de/

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - see update, I manage to get the input value as classes

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the fiddle

Comment: @JasonF. Thanks, upvotes are always appreciated ;-)

Comment: @DanielApt, Sorry, new to here and think my rep has to be above 15 to be able to for some reason

Comment: @JasonF I added a simplified answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the search values as classes on the `li` elements then you can massively simplify your logic by selecting the elements by class.

To do this, simply remove the whitespace in the search term and replace it with a `.`. Try this:

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (searchTerm == '') {
    $('.filterlist > li').show();
  } else {
    try {
      var selector = '.' + searchTerm.replace(/\s+/g, '.');
      $('.filterlist > li').hide().filter(selector).show();
    } catch(e) {
      // only to bury the error when a selector is built whilst the user is mid-typing
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="box" type="text" placeholder="Search">

<ul class="filterlist" style="list-style:none;">
  <li class="red">1. red</li>
  <li class="blue">2. blue</li>
  <li class="red blue yellow">3. red blue yellow</li>
  <li class="blue red yellow">4. blue red yellow</li>
  <li class="red yellow">5. red yellow</li>
  <li class="red green">6. red green</li>
</ul>
```

Note that the `try`/`catch` is only required here to stop the errors which would occur when a searchTerm is in the process of being entered and the generated selector is invalid - eg `.red,.`. If you changed the design to use a button you could potentially remove that try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition in your solution needs to be changed.

You can find the changed and working code in fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/9vhhvgb3/

The changes are 
     `for(var i=0;i<subValues.length;i++){
        if(text.indexOf(subValues[i]) > -1){
            nodeToDisplay = true;
        }else{
            nodeToDisplay = false;
        }
      }
      if(nodeToDisplay){
        node.show();

      }
      else {
        node.hide();
      }`

Comment: almost got it, but what if we were looking for the exact match 'red yellow', currently is will show all items with red and yellow.  Also just noticed using ', ' does not show all items i.e. blue, green only shows green items